# Installing OSX 10.7 on MacBook 4,1

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, macbook

I am not a Apple user, but I want to upgrade a MacBook 4,1 to Lion 10.7/10.7.5 but when I boot from the CD with the dmg file I bought from app store, I click on Reinstall Mac OS X but I get a message saying *You can't upgrade this version of Max OS X*. I think this happens because I did not format the partition prior to the installation but I want to make sure this is the reason, since if I format it and the setup wouldn't let me install Lion, I would be stuck without an OS.

I currently have 10.5.X installed and my Mac have 4GB of RAM as required for Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to upgrade your OSX to 10.6.x (Snow Leopard) first before you can actually upgrade it to 10.7.x (Lion).

Comment: You are correct but I found a method online that instructs you to edit the file that holds the data about the curernt version, and when I've edited it from 10.5.8 to 10.6.8 setup went on flawlessly and OS X is up and running like a lion :-)

Answer (score 0):

When mac start up, just format the HDD with disc manager (forgot the right name for that operation) and then install 10.7.5Lion. I have done this way several times - it works! :)